# How do I capture a variable in GTM from another pixel present on the confirmation page?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm looking to capture an order ID from the omniture tracking script present on the confirmation/thank you page, and store this in GTM as a variable that I can use to populate another tracking pixel. Here is how the script looks:

`<div omniture-tracking-script="" page-name="Thank You" events="purchase" sku="8370399913709911251799000" ipid="08ba8410-0451-41d8-b32c-7f0bb3f67bbe-2069-20ababddbd536eccda482f762144cd90ce96fd9b" orderid="5001519438" trackingtotalamount="0" currency="GBP" class="ng-isolate-scope">`

I thought I might be able to scrape from the DOM element using ID as the selection method, and setting the element ID to orderid, but this doesnt seem to be working.

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: "orderid" is not the same as "id". You would have to use "CSS selector" rather than "id" and then set "attribute name" to "orderid". Also you would need to make sure that your tag fires only after the tracking script has loaded (so DOM ready rather than pageload). I don't know if GTM's selector engine accepts non-standard attributes, and have no time to test this, so I can't make this an answer, but maybe it's enough to get you going.

Answer (score 0):

if you can get the variable in your code base, then you can do :

1. get the value in your code
2. push this to datalayer
3. use "dataLayer variable" in GTM to get the value and set it as a variable in GTM

or you can:

1. get the value in your code
2. save it as a cookie
3. use "third-party cookie" in GTM to get the value and set it as a variable in GTM

just in case you don't know how to define the variable
[image]

Comment: The value isn't present anywhere i can access it other than in this tag unfortunately! That's why I'm trying to scrape it from here. Is it possible?

Comment: sorry I don't get the question. where is this tag? GTM?

Comment: Sorry - probably not being very clear! The existing tag is direct on the page and I have no access to this. I'm looking to capture the orderID from this tag by scraping the DOM - my issue is that I don't know how to tell GTM where to look on the page to capture it and save as a custom variable. All the guides online refer to using the class in CSS, but this won't work here?

Comment: so in your code (not GTM, but on the page where you plan to scrap the DOM), you  run "const oderId = $('.ng-isolate-scope').attr('orderid'); window.dataLayer.push({orderId});" And then in the GTM you create a variable "orderId" with type "dataLayer variable". why this doesn't work? you don't need to tell GTM to capture it. You capture it and send it to GTM